# How can I detect what exact version of Exchange server I connect to with Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange

I would like to know how can I find the exact version (full version string) of Exchange Server I am connecting to form my intranet.

I my specific case I do have a Mac and Outlook 2011 but I want to see what version I do have on the server side.

For example the Exchange server connection is made by using HTTPS to a an URL like `https://eurcas01.eur.example.com/ews/exchange.asmx'

Note, I tried to contact internal IT support, but they were not able to provide an answer for this... so I have to try to find the answer myself :p

Comment: Run wireshark and see if you can scrape a version number from the handshake?

Answer (score 10):

Right click the outlook icon in the task bar while holding the CRTL key then select connection status. Move the scroll bar all the way over to the right to see the version number, and compare the number with the below Versions

```
Microsoft Exchange Server 2000:         6.0.4417 or higher
Microsoft Exchange Server 2000 SP1:     6.0.4712 or higher
Microsoft Exchange Server 2000 SP2:     6.0.5762 or higher
Microsoft Exchange Server 2000 SP3:     6.0.6249 or higher
Microsoft Exchange Server 2003:         6.5.6944 or higher
Microsoft Exchange Server 2003 SP1:     6.5.7226 or higher
Microsoft Exchange Server 2003 SP2:     6.5.7638 or higher
Microsoft Exchange Server 2007:         8.0.685.24 or higher
```

They don't specify a version for 2010 so I'll include it: The RTM version of Exchange 2010 is 14.00.0639.021 and the SP1 version of Exchange 2010 is 14.01.0218.015.

[Source](https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/determine-the-version-of-microsoft-exchange-my-account-connects-to-HA010117038.aspx)

Comment: +1 Great find.  It also shows you which domain controllers you are connected to.

Comment: Task bar? The questioner mentioned they had a Mac.

Comment: @BurhanAli your right I didn't even notice that... What would like me to do? I can delete/edit or?

Comment: @Kyle Leave it to be honest. I found it a useful answer for finding out this information on my Windows machine. Maybe edit it though to clarify that your instructions refer to Windows.

Comment: This does not work with Office 2011 for Mac :P

Comment: @SorinSbarnea I'd be surprised if it worked for any version of Office for mac. I apparently had issues reading that day and had answered it as if you were using Windows. I left the answer cause others found it useful.

Comment: My version returns 8.3.297.1 . Any idea what that is?

Comment: @ChaimKut 8.3 is 2007 sp3

Comment: And what if you don't have outlook?  Yes, I know that was not the original question.  But I'm looking around first before I post a question.

Comment: In reply to my last comment you can use a web browser and OWA (if your Exchange administrator allows it).  Select the "? -> About" menu entry (at least with the "Version: 14.3.301.0" server that I am using).

Answer (score 3):

Currently the only way to find the version was to access the web interface (OWA). Inside the Account section you will a numeric version written in the left sidebar.

Comment: This did not work for my OWA version (presumably, Exchange2010_SP2 or "14.3.210.2")

Comment: In the OWA I am using today, you can get to that information from the ? -> About menu entry (the ? is to the right of the Options menu in the top right).  It turns out the info there for me currently shows: "Version: 14.3.301.0"

Comment: ... and "Mailbox server Microsoft Exchange version: 14.3.123.0" and "Client Access server version: 14.3.123.0" and "Exchange Client Access server .NET Framework version: 2.0.50727.5485"